# Dúvida com restauração de banco no oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

estou com uma dificuldade, tenho o meu banco local, oracle XE, estou adicionando um backup do banco que recebi, fiz as seguintes configurações descritas, após finalizar o restore do banco com sucesso, fiz uma conexão com este banco no meu localhost usando o usuário e senha criado anteriormente, mais não e visualizado nenhuma tabela?

```
--criando uma tablespace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLESPACE ATLASCARGOHBSAETC LOGGING DATAFILE 'C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/oradata/XE/ATLASCARGOHBSAETC.dbf'
SIZE 100m AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100m EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL;

Resultado = OK
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--criamos um usuário no Oracle e vincular este usuário ao tablespace chamada ATLASCARGOHBSAETC.

CREATE USER us_atlascargohbsaetc IDENTIFIED BY 123 DEFAULT TABLESPACE ATLASCARGOHBSAETC
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON  ATLASCARGOHBSAETC;

Resultado = OK

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

--grant para o usuário logar e abrir uma sessão
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO us_atlascargohbsaetc;

Resultado = OK
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

--recuperar backup
impdp \"/ as sysdba\" DIRECTORY= DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=HBSA_ETC
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no usuário, adicionei o mesmo usuário usado na criação do backup, assim as tabelas foram listadas.